# Scanner não está pegando todas as linhas

Tags: java, arquivo, scanner

Eu tenho um arquivo com 7 milhões de linhas, mas o meu código pega no máximo 63000 e não retorna erro nenhum.

```
Scanner sc2 = null;
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("./assets/words.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    int cont = 0;

    while(sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = sc2.next();
        System.out.println(s + " - " + cont);
        cont++;
    }
```

Comment: As dicas abaixo não serviram?

Comment: Desculpa, na hora que eu fui dar a responta como certo ainda tinha que esperar 7 minutos e acabei esquecendo, obrigado por me lembrar :D

Comment: Se puder implementar sua resposta dizendo a diferença entre `FileReader` e `File`, pode ajudar os outros no futuro :D

Comment: Pronto, acrescentado :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que possa ser por limitações de uso de memória da classe `File`, tente da forma abaixo, sugerida numa [pergunta semelhante no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19813760/5524514):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
String line = "";
while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    // do something
}
```

Ou se não quiser trocar toda a implementação, experimente trocar `File` por `FileReader`:

```
Scanner sc2 = null;
    try {
        sc2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("./assets/words.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    int cont = 0;

    while(sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = sc2.next();
        System.out.println(s + " - " + cont);
        cont++;
    }
```

A diferença entre [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) e [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) é que o primeiro é apenas uma representação abstrata do arquivo, o segundo é a classe para leitura de caracteres de arquivos, ou seja, `File` não representa um arquivo, e sim, seu caminho apenas, enquanto `FileReader` é a representação dos dados(caracteres) deste arquivo.

**Referências:**

- [Scanner reading large file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19813760/5524514)
- [Java FileReader vs File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28884489/5524514)